# Password problem x11vnc

Tags: password, opensuse, remote, x11vnc

I am an absolute starter on Linux and I am operating on an OpenSUSE Leap 42.1 and here is my situation:

I was given a task to build a PC with very similar configs and properties to one already in operation. The steps I took are based on very brief instructions from a colleague and on going through the files from the already-built computer.

I was able to correctly set up the autostart for x11vnc server by creating a symbolic link from the executable to the "autostart-scripts" folder:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/x11vnc /home/"myusernamefolder"/.config/autostart-scripts/x11vnc
```

However, my problem is password-related... Using the terminal, I store the desired password as follows:

```
x11vnc -storepasswd "mypassword" /home/"myusernamefolder"/.vnc/passwd
```

Then, I create the following file:

```
edit /home/"myusernamefolder"/.x11vncrc
```

Containing the following:

```
display :0
rfbauth /home/"myusernamefolder"/.vnc/passwd
forever
bg
```

Then, when I try to remote access from another computer, there is an authentication error, as if the password I type on the VNC client does not correspond to the one I stored on the server...
I already tried not setting up a password and not creating the file above and the remote access happens successfully, but I really need this remote access to have a password.

Any tips? Can you see where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I was able to correctly set up the autostart for x11vnc server by
>   creating a symbolic link from the executable to the
>   "autostart-scripts" folder:

Creating a symbolic is not needed.

Store your password in `/home/user/.vnc/passwd`

**Encrypted**

```
x11vnc -storepasswd mypassword /home/user/.vnc/passwd
```

**Clear Text**

```
echo mypassword > /home/user/.vnc/password
```

---

Create an autostart script at `/home/user/.config/autostart/x11vnc.desktop`. Desktop files in this directory are executed as soon as the GUI loads.

**x11vnc.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=X11VNC Server
Comment=Share this desktop by VNC
Icon=computer
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
Exec=x11vnc -forever -shared -display :0 -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd
```

Look at last line

Use this if password is in **Encrypted** form

```
Exec=x11vnc -forever -shared -display :0 -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd
```

**Clear Text** saved in file

```
Exec=x11vnc -forever -shared -display :0 -passwdfile /home/user/.vnc/passwd
```

Clear Text via **Command Line** (not recommended)

```
Exec=x11vnc -forever -shared -display :0 -passwd mypassword
```

---

- `forever` option is used to make x11vnc server persistent. It won't exit after the first connection get disconnected.
- `shared` options is used to allow more than 1 connections on same display

Comment: is `/home/user/` to be replaced by whatever is my `$HOME`?

Comment: Your answer still works after 5 years with Lubuntu + LxQt + x11vnc + Jump Desktop for Mac OS.